# python tornado linkedin auth

Tags: python, tornado

I would like to authenticate to `linkedin.com` and get some content

I use `requests` python module and do something like this:

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

client = requests.Session()

HOMEPAGE_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com'
LOGIN_URL = HOMEPAGE_URL + '/uas/login-submit'

html = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
csrf = soup.find(id="loginCsrfParam-login")['value']

login_information = {
    'session_key':'my_login',
    'session_password':'my_password',
    'loginCsrfParam': csrf,
}

client.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_information)

content = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL + 'vsearch/c').content
```

And, got the content, all right,

But, now I want to use tornado framework to do the same work

I get `loginCsrfParam` in the similar way and make post request:

```
login_information = {
    'session_key':'my_login',
    'session_password':'my_password',
    'loginCsrfParam':csrf
}

body = urllib.urlencode(login_information)
http_client.fetch(LOGIN_URL,
          handle_request_post,
          method='POST', 
          headers=None,
          body=body)
```

And after arriving response

```
http_client.fetch(HOMEPAGE_URL + '/vsearch/c', 
          handle_request_get_content,
          method = 'GET')
```

But I get simply a login page

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Tornado's AsyncHTTPClient doesn't have any concept of a session; each request is independent. It looks like requests.Session is transferring something from the login request to the vsearch request, probably cookies. You'll need to handle the Set-Cookie header from the login request and transfer the cookies to any following requests (perhaps using the [http.cookiejar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html) module)